# Error while Installing Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, failed-installation

I was installing VS Code on Windows. 
System type : 32-bit Operating System, x64 based processor.
I downloaded the exe file from the web : [VSCodeDownloads](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Case 1: I downloaded the exe file as marked in the image given below:

[image]

After hitting the run, the following error was displayed:

[image: Error]

The same error encountered when I tried to install the Insider version.

Case 2: I downloaded the exe file (marked as 2) in the above image.
I could successfully install that. And I am using efficiently.

---

Though I have x64 based processor, it showed me that unexpected error.
Please, clarify why was the error appearing? what was the mistake? And how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd advise editing your question to include the text of the error instead of linking to an image. People are more likely to help you if you make it easy for them to help you.

Comment: can you check your system properties and verify the whether it is 32bit or 64?

Comment: I checked. It is 32-bit OS and x64 based processor(that is processor architecture).

Comment: You should use an install file matching your OS, not your processor. So in your case you should DL and use the 32bit version not the 64bit one.

Comment: Thanks Hakan ERDOGAN. I got it. x64 displayed was actually 64bit OS.

Comment: And the default download button is for 32bit OS version. But the occurred error is pointing to the version of processor.
And I have x64 based which is the requirement according to this error. . Isn't this unexpectable?